# How to do a Many to Many join in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I have two tables (and a joining table)

Fruit -> Schedule

A fruit can have many schedules and a schedule can have many fruits.

I need a linq query using the repository pattern to join them, how do I do this?

```
var query = from p in _fruitRepository.Table
            join s in _scheduleRepository.Table on p.[SomeProperty] on s.[SomeProperty]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Show us your entities.

Comment: you can use SelectMany()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have `Schedules` navigation property in your `Fruit` class. Us it:

```
var items = from f in _context.Fruits
            from s in f.Schedules
            select new { f, s }
```

Comment: Do you know how to get information from the joining table i.e. FruitSchedules?

Comment: I don't think it's mapped in a way that allows you to get information from there. What kind of information are you looking for? This table should only have 2 columns: `FruitId` and `ScheduleId`.

Comment: Yes that is correct, it has 2 columns however I need this information to construct my models appropriately otherwise I will have no idea what Fruits are connected to which schedules.

Comment: If EF can't do it I will need to build an explicit entity to handle the join.